# Авторасширение столбцов Datagrid в WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid

В старом проекте у меня всегда работал параметр `Width="*"` у `DataGridTextColumn`. Но в новых проектах оно работает некорректно. Может кто сталкивался с подобным?

Код

```
    <DataGrid x:Name="dgr" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Номер абонента" Width="*" Binding="{Binding NumberAbonent}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="ФИО" Width="*" Binding="{Binding FIO}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Номер договора" Width="*" Binding="{Binding NumberDogovora}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Лицевой счёт" Width="*" Binding="{Binding LicevoySchet}"/>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Действие" Width="*">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Button x:Name="checkFullInfo_btn" Content="Открыть" Click="checkFullInfo_btn_Click"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

Как работало раньше:
[image: Правильное отображение]

Как работает сейчас:
[image: Неправильное отображение]

Answer (score 0):

Нашёл ответ: если у контейнера (`Page` или `Window`), в который вложен `DataGrid` явно не указано значение `Width`, а, например, только `MinWidth`, тогда происходит такая ситуация.